# MySQL If exsists insert into or else do something else

Tags: mysql, insert, conditional-statements

I'm having some difficulty putting a conditional into MySQL. I've been trying to create a query that will go through all of the column titled email and if it exists I want to do something like this:
If an email exists I want it to take the existing value of the column correct and add the php variable $correct to it. But if an email does not exist then I want it to add a new record with the values $email into the column email and $correct into column correct.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here's what I have and does not work:

```
IF  (SELECT * FROM facebookqs WHERE email = '$email' > 0)
UPDATE facebookqs SET correct = correct + '$correct' where email ='$email' 
Else
Insert into facebookqs (email, correct) VALUES ('$email', '$correct')
```

Comment: You could take a look at the `replace into` feature? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `email` has a `UNIQUE` constraint, you should use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO facebookqs (email, correct) VALUES ('$email', '$correct')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE correct = correct + '$correct'
```

See also my answer for this other Stack Overflow question: [INSERT IGNORE vs INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/548570#548570)

Answer (score 3):

Your missing an `EXISTS` statement and the `THEN` and `END IF` in the `IF`

```
IF  (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM facebookqs WHERE email = '$email')) THEN
  UPDATE facebookqs SET correct = correct + '$correct' WHERE email ='$email';
ELSE
  INSERT INTO facebookqs (email, correct) VALUES ('$email', '$correct');
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks more like what I want to do but I still get a sql syntax error =/

Comment: It says: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF  (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM facebookqs WHERE email = 'test')) THEN
  UPDATE faceb' at line 1

Comment: If you notice i accidentally deleted the space between the WHERE clause in the update statement and the email columnname.  If you copied my code word for word perhaps this is your problem.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, still doesn't work. It seems once the exist part comes in I start with the errors.

Comment: @Trey Are you using this IF statement instead a stored procedure of mysql? I was doing the same mistake and was getting syntax error. You must create a stored procedure with this IF block inside it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18288088

Answer (score 1):

Use the `REPLACE` method, explained here: http://blogs.coldbuffer.com/inserting-or-updating-records-using-mysql-replace From their example:

```
REPLACE INTO pet (id, type, name) VALUES(1, 'Dog', 'Pluto');
```

which given your example should be (haven't tested it yet)

```
REPLACE INTO facebookqs (email, correct) VALUES ('$email', '$correct');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to select the e-mail column only? Or do you have multiple columns that contain e-mail addresses? If you have multiple columns with email then you would need to say where col1Email = '$email' or col2Email='$email'... etc. To get a count of the rows try
SELECT COUNT(*) from facebookqs where col1Email = '$email' or col2Email='$email'.