# How to check if a column exist inside a table, and preform action based on the result

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL 5.5.16.

I'm trying to check if a certain column exists in one of my tables. If it is I want to update its `type & collation` and if it isn't I want to add it to the table.

I've read similar posts [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490991/mysql-if-exsists-insert-into-or-else-do-something-else) about `IF EXISTS` statement. But I'm getting an error with my query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'e4s_account_details' AND column_name = 'accountID') THEN
   ALTER TABLE 'e4s_account_details' CHANGE 'accountID' 'accountID' INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ELSE 
   ALTER TABLE 'e4s_account_details' ADD COLUMN 'accountID' INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
END IF;
```

The error I get is:

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'e4s_acco' at line 1`

BTW, If I only query this:

```
(SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'e4s_account_details' AND column_name = 'accountID');
```

I get no error and the table+column information is returned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219714/check-if-column-exists-before-alter-table-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use this syntax directly with `select` query instead you can make `stored procedure` or query with `information schema` table for doing same.

Comment: Thanks for the help, 2 more little questions: can a stored procedure be executed from a `.sql` file ? and, What do you mean by "query with `information schema` table for doing same" ?

Comment: for 1st yes we can execute and for 2nd check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/mysql-alter-syntax-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists