# Select if exist else insert?

Tags: mysql

```
IF EXISTS (select * from users where username = 'something') THEN
    select id from users where username = 'something';
ELSE 
    insert into users (username) values ('something');
END IF;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your statement is fine as it is. Only problem is, you can't use it like a normal query. Control structures like `IF` or `WHILE` are only allowed in stored procedures or functions.

Just create a procedure like this:

```
delimiter $$

create procedure select_or_insert()
begin

IF EXISTS (select * from users where username = 'something') THEN
    select id from users where username = 'something';
ELSE 
    insert into users (username) values ('something');
END IF;

end $$
```

and call it like this:

```
call select_or_insert();
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like  this:-

```
if exists( select * from mytable where field = 'something') 
begin
   select somefield from mytable where field = 'something';
end
else
 begin
    insert into users (username) values ('something');
end
```

or

```
if not exists( select * from mytable where field = 'something') 
begin
    insert into users (username) values ('something');       
end
else
 begin
    select somefield from mytable where field = 'something';
 end
```

Although both the above queries are same.

or try this using if:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from mytable where users = 'something')
    select field from mytable where users = 'something'
else
    into mytable (users) values ('something')
```

Here is the [SQLFIDDLEDEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b5ea)

Comment: @cheshirecatalyst:- COuld you please try now. I am sure this will work!!:)

Comment: Well I think we were missing the ';' . I have also updated with one more option. Hope this works now ;)

Comment: Try to remove the End If; ...Lets  see what you get. Although I am surprised that it not working for you.!! :(

Comment: I think you are doing something very wrong. Could you please edit your question and paste you original query which you are running. As I am sure everything above is working fine. You may be missing something ;)

Comment: Have edited it to show exactly what i put in last time, if i use it without the END IF; it errors on the ELSE

Comment: @cheshirecatalyst:- Updated my answer with the working SQLFIDDLEDEMO. Please check if that help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the accepted answer, but only requiring one SELECT call (written for MySQL):

```
delimiter $$

create procedure select_or_insert()
begin

SET @myId := (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'something');

IF (ISNULL(@myId))
    THEN 
        INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ('something');                 
END IF;

end $$
```

If desired, selecting newly-inserted elements can then be efficiently selected by using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function:

```
SELECT @myId := LAST_INSERT_ID();
```