# MySQL query not works (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector, database-connection

I try to update my MYSQL table with this code.

```
string sqlquery = String.Format("if exists(select 1 from orders where id =\" {0}\" ) begin update orders set customer_id = \"{1}\", total = \"{2}\", fio = \"{3}\", adress =\" {4}\" where id = \"{0}\" end else begin insert into orders (id, customer_id, total, fio, adress) values(\"{0}\", \"{1}\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\", \"{4}\") end", id, customer_id, total, fio, adress);

MySqlCommand addCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery.ToString(), connection);
addCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I have this error

```
Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists(select 1 from orders where id = 1913 ) begin update orders set custome' at line 1
```

Database

[image]

What wrong in query?

Thank's for help!

Comment: Post here what you get in the `sqlquery` on runtime.

Comment: your column name is '1'?

Comment: I get error when code launches@feeeper

Comment: Added screen of table in question@mwisnicki

Comment: It seems that the quotes around `id` are missing in your `if exists (select ... ` part. At least when I look at the error message you get. You should not create queries with `String.Format` or concatenating but use parameterized queries. 

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Comment: Okay, how I need to write my code ? @derpirscher

Comment: @Eugene, have you looked at the link I gave you?

Comment: Yes. So I need  to use parameters like this `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);` ? 
@derpirscher

Comment: Okay I write query with parameters, but I still have error.@derpirscher

Comment: And have question, about what quotes you talking? @derpirscher

Comment: with quotes i meant, `id` is a varchar and must therefore be enclosed in `'` (ie quotes) from the original error message it seems that these quotes are missing. But that could only be a problem with the error message. From this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286532/select-if-exist-else-insert it seems that such constructs are not allowed in a query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123503/discussion-between-eugene-and-derpirscher).

Answer (score 2):

why dont you do it in more elegant way:Something like.:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
 { 
command.CommandText = "if exists(select 1 from orders where id =@id)    
 begin 
 update orders set customer_id = @customer_id, total = @total, fio = @fio, adress =@adress where id = @id end 
 else
  begin insert into orders (id, customer_id, total, fio, adress) values(@id, @customer_id, @total, @fio,@adress) end";

   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", val1);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", val2);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", val3);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fio", val4);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adress", val5);
   connection.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   connection.Close();
 }
```

Comment: much better in terms of neatness

Comment: missed closed bracket in `if` condition.Check now.

Comment: Same thing too.


I found this `Control structures like IF or WHILE are only allowed in stored procedures or functions.`

Comment: I checked and it works fine on my machine.Though in sqlserver CE,it may not allowed(as per your link)

Comment: @Vicky You are using MS SQL Server, where such constructs are allowed in queries, the OP is using MySql where such control structures are only allowed in stored procedures but not in queries.