How can I let each id correspond to a unique set of rows in MySQL?
I have the following database that I want to use for logging networks:
CREATE TABLE ip (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    address VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL,  -- IPv4 or IPv6
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (address)
);

CREATE TABLE mac (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    address VARBINARY(100) NOT NULL,  -- hardware address (usually MAC)
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (address)
);

CREATE TABLE network (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE network_configuration (
    network INT NOT NULL,
    mac INT NOT NULL,
    ip INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (network, mac, ip),
    INDEX (mac, ip, network),  -- For searching a network
    FOREIGN KEY (network) REFERENCES network(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (mac) REFERENCES mac(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ip) REFERENCES ip(id)
);

When logging a network, I do not want any rows to be inserted if the network (combinations of MAC and IP addresses) already exists. In that case I just want to get the corresponding id from the network table.
To be more clear, I want the following query to give a different output for each value of <id>.
SELECT mac, ip FROM network_configuration WHERE network=<id>
Example data:
INSERT INTO ip (id, address) VALUES (1, X'7f000001');  -- 127.0.0.1
INSERT INTO ip (id, address) VALUES (2, X'c0a80101');  -- 192.168.1.1
INSERT INTO ip (id, address) VALUES (3, X'c0a80102');  -- 192.168.1.2

INSERT INTO mac (id, address) VALUES (1, X'3288a01e0fad');
INSERT INTO mac (id, address) VALUES (2, X'e2e1700bd5fb');
INSERT INTO mac (id, address) VALUES (3, X'8b1095dfe2eb');
INSERT INTO mac (id, address) VALUES (4, X'e4d9432afddb');

INSERT INTO network (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO network (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO network (id) VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO network_configuration (network, mac, ip) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO network_configuration (network, mac, ip) VALUES (1, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO network_configuration (network, mac, ip) VALUES (2, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO network_configuration (network, mac, ip) VALUES (2, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO network_configuration (network, mac, ip) VALUES (3, 3, 1);

(notice how network 2 and 3 share a MAC/IP pair, but are still different networks because network 2 also has an other MAC/IP pair)
Now let's say I encounter an instance of network 2, that is, mac/ip combinations 8b1095dfe2eb/127.0.0.1 and e4d9432afddb/192.168.1.2.
What is the best way to get this number 2 and not fill my database by making an unnecessary fourth network?
I think I have a make a select query where I input all MAC and IP addresses, but this involves multiple rows and I don't really see how to do that.

I think this has been asked and answered already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286532/select-if-exist-else-insert

That is a different question. What makes this different is that a network here consists of multiple rows of mac and ip combinations.

to have this question reopened you should provide some sample data, expected results and your best attempt.

Please define the expected results then.  Do you want 1 ID, or all the ID's which are duplicate?  This could be done using set base logic in a procedure.  Select all those that exist already to obtain the id's in a temp table.  Insert all those that did not exist; then return the temp a table results for all the "Existing" ids...  Where are the configurations you're inserting sourced?  Are they in a table are you looping thorough a local data set row by row?  This could be done as a set or row by row which is slower but provides additional control points.

As it stands the question  lacks specifics to provide a more complete response IMO.

Mac address is ALWAYS exactly 12 hex characters. Why reserve varbinary(100) space? Even if you want binary, 12 hex characters reduces to 48 bits, which is binary(6)

@LelioFaieta I added example data

@xQbert The idea is to not have duplicates in the first place.

@JoelCoehoorn If you must know, I'm storing the hardware address that I get from Java, which is usually the MAC address, but can be something entirely different. I added a comment for a reason next to it.

if you want to create a new network when you encounter a new mac/ip combination, you should have a separate network table with just an autoincrement id, and change your existing table name to network_mac_ip or similar.

@ysth That makes sense, I've edited my question to use this.

I agree with @ysth, you need to create an additional layer that stores the sets of IP / mac addresses under the same id and you can assign these set ids to the networks instead of the combination of IP / MAC addresses

there's not much different here than the suggested question.  you likely want a unique(mac,ip) on network_configuration.   do a select on mac and ip, if it succeeds you are done, if not insert a new network and insert the configuration (in a transacion).  if the insert fails due to a race, rollback and retry the select.

@ysth But if I use UNIQUE(mac, ip) I cannot have the same MAC/IP combination on multiple networks, right? That must stay possible.

then I misunderstand your whole question.  I thought you wanted to not add an extra network when the mac/ip already exists but start a new network if they do not.  if you can have it in multiple networks, it seems like you should know something that identifies the network besides the new mac & ip already, and use that to look up a network id?

@ysth No, I need to use MAC/IP for that.

I don't see how you can have it both ways.  how do you know if your new mac/ip are on the existing network (and which one?) or a new one?

@ysth Two networks are considered the same when they have all MAC/IP pairs in common.

so you know not just a pair, but a whole bunch of pairs, and want to see if they exist in a single network already?   that's just e.g. select id from network_configuration where (mac,ip) in ((?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?)) group by id having count(*)=4  but unless you always know all the devices on the network, it seems like that could still produce false positives or negatives.

@ysth When I execute SELECT network FROM network_configuration WHERE (mac, ip) IN ((3, 1), (4, 3)) GROUP BY network HAVING COUNT(*) = 2, it gives network 2 correctly, but when I execute SELECT network FROM network_configuration WHERE (mac, ip) IN ((3, 1)) GROUP BY network HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 it gives both 2 and 3, while I only want network 3 in that case.

so you want to verify that the set of mac/ip pairs exactly matches?  are you sure you want to create a new "network" anytime a device is removed?  several ways to add the additional check.  one is select network from network_configuration where network in (select network from network_configuration where (mac,ip) in ((?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?)) group by network having count(*)=4) group by network having count(*)=4

@ysth Yeah, I just posted an answer

oh, just saw it :)

Based on the comment by ysth, I came up with this query for the example case:
SELECT network FROM network_configuration WHERE network IN (
    SELECT network FROM network_configuration
    WHERE (mac, ip) IN ((3, 1), (4, 3))
    GROUP BY network HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
GROUP BY network HAVING COUNT(*) = 2


you do likely want a unique (mac,ip,network) (in that order to be useful for this query) or just a mulitcolumn index if you don't want unique

Alright, good one. Since I already added a PRIMARY KEY (network, mac, ip) the uniqueness is already implied and I could also add INDEX (mac, ip, network). Or maybe INDEX (mac, ip)?

with network will make the subselect a covered query, slightly more efficient

Alright thanks! Hey, I don't know if you care, but since you basically answered my question, if you copy-paste my query and put it in an answer I'll accept it and delete my answer.

happy leaving it as is

Perhaps your example is incorrect?  "127.0.0.1" and "192.168.1.2" are special IPs; they presumably will never be seen from outside the LAN.
I suggest that the schema is 'over-normalized'.  This should suffice?
CREATE TABLE network
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE networks (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    network INT NOT NULL,
    mac BINARY(6) NOT NULL,    -- maybe NULL if you don't have mac?
    ip VARBINARY(16) NULL,     -- null when LAN
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
    UNIQUE (network, mac, IP),
    UNIQUE (mac),
    UNIQUE (IP)
);

Even if this is not sufficient for your application, play around with it to see if this is a better starting point.
These are local to LANs and do not make sense from outside.  (Please correct me if I am wrong):
127.0.0.*   -- or is it 127.*.*.*
192.168.*.*
10.*.*.*
11.*.*.*

Note that UNIQUE (but not PRIMARY KEY) allows multiple rows with NULL.

This does not address my question in any way.

Once you avoid the LAN IPs, I think the better schema will shine.

The question is an SQL question, for which I already have an answer. You have no idea why I'm storing LAN ip addresses and it doesn't matter for the question.

@user42723 FWIW I also almost suggested you junk the extra tables and just store the actual addresses in your configuration table.  the ids get gain you almost nothing.

@ysth Alright, that's going to make my code a bit easier to write.

LAN IP addresses are not UNIQUE.
